# Device state not changing to silent mode

Tags: java, android

I have been recently working on a small project recently, i am facing a little problem.

**Problem Appearing:**
Device state not changing to Silent Mode when Message sent from another device.

**Workflow:**

Sms containg "Msilent"  sent from another Device >
Victims Device receives the sms and reads the string and recognizes the keyword which is "Msilent" >
Victims phone ringing profile changing to silent mode.

Device Android Version : Lollipop 5.0

***Here is my Code:***

IncomingSms.java

```
package android.yu;

/**
 * Created by Mahesh on 15-01-2017.
 */

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.Context.AUDIO_SERVICE;

/**
 * Created by Mahesh on 09-01-2017.
 */

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private AudioManager maudio;


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        maudio=(AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";

        if (myBundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");

            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                String format = myBundle.getString("format");
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);

                /*strMessage += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                strMessage += " : ";*/
                strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
               // strMessage += "\n";
            }

            Log.v("SMS", strMessage);
            if (strMessage.contains("Msilent"))
                maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package android.yu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.yu">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter android:priority="500">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your receiver in the main activity.